# Can complex object be saved fro slots in ibm watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Is there any way of saving complex context in ibm watson conversation from slots.
For eg if i have to save in case of bank Employee name inside account number

```
{

  "context":{

    "accountNo":{
      "value":"12345678",
      "AccountType":{
        "value":"savings"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

can this hierarchy be made using slots.

Such as

`@accountNumber` goes in  `accountNo.value`

`@AccountType` goes in `accountNo.AccountType.value`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your doubt, but, maybe this information will help you. If you want to save the `value` from `@accountNumber` and `@AccountType` entity inside the context variable in this JSON, you can set with:

```
{
  "context":{
    "accountNo":{
      "value":"<? @accountNumber ?>",
      "AccountType":{
        "value":"<? @AccountType ?>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for access these values you can use the `$accountNo.value` and `$AccountType.value`

But with slots, you can check for the `@entity` and save as `$someVariable` in the config. Like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843805/watson-conversation-service-using-slots-with-operators/45846302#45846302) from one IBM Professional @Simon O'Doherty:

[image]

**Obs.:** In this case you need to change the `Check for 1: @accountNumber` and `Check for 2: @AccountType` and **save it as** `$accountNo` and `$AccountType`.

**Obs.:** The value of the entity needs to be typed from the user before, and this value will be stored in this context variable when we set.

Official Documentation Watson Conversation methods [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#methods-to-process-values).